# what it means by A dot B yields C in Elliptic Curve Cryptography?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I don't understand what the dot notation is. Is it like a multiplication operation or an addition operation or what? and how is that related to the Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem?
For example, [this site](https://qvault.io/2020/09/17/very-basic-intro-to-elliptic-curve-cryptography/) is explaining an example of dotting two points on the Elliptic Curve

Comment: It runs out [the point addition](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66288/18298)! It is based on the geometric tangent and chord ( correction, it is chord)

Comment: The tangent and chord rule and its relation to point additon to form a group is a long process to talk about ( especially the associativity). You can read it in a good book like Washinton's book. The ECC rely on the hardness of the [DLog](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76230/18298)  and for this, we need the scalar multiplicaiton as in the answer.

Comment: The nice [article](https://qvault.io/2020/09/17/very-basic-intro-to-elliptic-curve-cryptography/) motivating the question uses `cdot` (in letters) to denote point addition on an Elliptic Curve, and is about explanation how that works. I can't find any other source with that notation. It's commonly used $+$, and the article only uses another notation to distinguish point addition on the Elliptic Curve group from addition in the underlying field (I use $\boxplus$ to that effect [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/83317/555)).